# How to create custom subdomains for each unique username in django?

Tags: django, apache, django-models, django-admin, subdomain

I've been searching for a perfect solution to create a custom subdomains for each user, just like word press does for blogs in Django.

The problem is all the solutions on first 4 pages of google results are outdated.

I'm using apache, heroku, windows7. 
I've done the DNS management of setting (wildcard setting)

```
*.domainname.com
```

to

```
 appname.herokuapp.com
```

A link to documentation or step-by-step tutorial would be really helpful.

Thanks guys, love stackoverflow. To 10 million questions.

P.S. I'm n00b, please explain in easy terms and the required code of settings.py, urls.py, admin.py, models.py, views.py

(or links(sorry! Google is not being helpful))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which solution you mean is outdated but I'm using [django-subdomains](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Read the quick start and basic usage in documentation and i think you will understand what is going on.

Quick settings which i use (it is exactly the same as in documentation)

```
#settings.py
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls.account'


SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS = {
    None: 'myproject.urls.frontend',  # no subdomain, e.g. ``example.com``
    'www': 'myproject.urls.frontend',
    'api': 'myproject.urls.api',
}
```

in `myproject.urls.account` you map home url something like that

```
url(r'^$','user_view',name='userview'),
```

and when visitor prompt for `username.domain.com` django will redirect him on `user_view` defined in `myproject.urls.account`

In your `user_view` you can do something like that:

```
def user_view(request):
profile = Profiles.objects.get(username = request.subdomain)
....
```

Note: This is not the only possible configuration. Read docs for more.

Comment: I am not sure what is your point for linking me that thread :) Answer of @teilo is right, but i don't see any benefits from writing your own middleware. 
When i had a need for subdomains of each profile i remind on similar solution, but i found that django-subdomains is great library.